# When to use "lessen", when "decrease", and when "reduce"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Is it appropriate to say this:

> 1. I need to reduce the amount of money I spend per month.
> 2. I need to lessen the amount of money I spend per month.
> 3. I need to decrease the amount of money I spend per month.

I don't understand when to use "reduce", "decrease", and "lessen". Can you explain it, please?

Comment: "Reduce" would be most idiomatic, but it's basically a matter of personal choice.

Comment: I would use _reduce_, but the other two are both fine. _Decrease_ sounds a bit formal, _lessen_ sounds informal. (But I'm not saying that there is a scale of formality that you can rank the three on). I don't believe that the kind of answer you are looking for exists. All three words have very similar meanings, and I don't think there is any kind of systematic difference.

Comment: One specific context where I find it hard to imagine anyone using ***lessen*** is as an adjectival past participle in something like *My lessened bank balance after Xmas meant I couldn't take advantage of the January sales.* It might not sound *quite* so "unlikely" in other contexts - but so far as I can see, ***lessen*** is never the *first* choice for *any* context.

Answer (score 1):

Offhand I can't think of any contexts where the choice between ***reduce, lessen, decrease*** would make any difference to the *meaning* of an utterance. But [there are significant differences](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20decrease%20the%20amount%2Cwill%20reduce%20the%20amount%2Cwill%20lessen%20the%20amount&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20decrease%20the%20amount%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20reduce%20the%20amount%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20lessen%20the%20amount%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwill%20decrease%20the%20amount%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20reduce%20the%20amount%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20lessen%20the%20amount%3B%2Cc0) as regards how *common* each verb is...

[image]

Note that the above chart shows the *transitive* usage (someone or something ***causes*** the amount to become smaller). But here's [another chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20amount%20decreased%2Cthe%20amount%20reduced%2Cthe%20amount%20lessened&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20amount%20decreased%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20amount%20reduced%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20amount%20decreased%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20amount%20reduced%3B%2Cc0) showing the *intransitive* usage (the amount still becomes smaller, but no "agent" is specified)...

[image]

...where you'll note that ***lessen*** doesn't even occur often enough to chart.

---

My advice for learners would be to avoid using ***lessen*** at all (as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lessen&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clessen%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clessen%3B%2Cc0) shows, it's been falling in popularity for at least three centuries).

As regards the choice between the other two, it's pretty obvious ***reduce*** is significantly more common. But no-one would be likely to think you'd made an "uncommon, unusual" choice if you used ***decrease*** instead (particularly in intransitive contexts), so it doesn't really matter which one you use. There's no doubt that ***decrease*** has been gradually gaining traction, but it still lags well behind ***reduce***.

Comment: I think there are also formality and 'padding' factors. With 'The Government intends to reduce / lessen / decrease the amount it spends on pensions tax relief' and especially  'The Government intends to significantly reduce / lessen / decrease the amount it spends on pensions tax relief', there is less inclination towards 'reduce'. There are also fairly strong collocations, eg with the less favoured 'lessen': 'lessened the impact/influence of ...' // 'lessened the gap between rich ...' // 'lessened the probability/likelihood that ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Agreed. After writing the first line of my answer, I did actually think of *[diminish, soften] the **impact*** as a possible context where feasibly ***lessen*** might be "preferred". But as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lessen+the+impact%2Creduce+the+impact%2Cdecrease+the+impact&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clessen%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creduce%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecrease%20the%20impact%3B%2Cc0) shows, all it does is knock ***decrease*** into third place...

Comment: ...I still had that chart open in another browser window, so I've just tried your other suggestions (along with ***risk***, which seems to be about the most common noun to follow just about *all* of these and other "synonyms"). Sometimes ***lessen*** is "joint second" in the popularity stakes, but ***impact*** is the only context I could easily find where it was obviously more common than ***decrease*** (and ***reduce*** seemed to *always* be way out in front). There are definitely (small) context-dependent factors, but I don't think it's worth *learners* spending much time looking in to them.

Comment: ELU is now yet another site for learners?

Comment: Oops! "Senior moment" there! But I doubt many *native* speakers would ask such a question.

Comment: That probably applies to most of what we discuss here. But the mass of native speakers are the ones generating the stats we're discussing, automatically defining acceptability / idiomaticity.

Comment: True, but I'd probably have VTCed as POB rather than spend all that time looking up usage charts if I'd realised which site I was on. Whatever - it's here now, so it can stay.