# Can "lessen" be used interchangeably with "reduce"?

Tags: meaning, differences

Can "lessen" be interchangeably used with "reduce"?

The government is implementing its new policy to **reduce** unemployment rate.

Is it okay to use "lessen" instead of using "reduce"?

Could "lessen" be used when we're talking about rates?

Comment: Hello, bryce, welcome to ELU.  Did you look up the two words (which are certainly very close in meaning) to see whether there are significant differences?  Have a look at them in Merriam-Webster Dictionary for 'reduce":  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reduce  and for "lessen":  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lessen.  See if you can find any contexts in which "lessen" can be used but not "reduce" or in which "reduce" can be used and not "lessen".  I think you will find the answer yourself.  If you want to be sure, try Collins or Cambridge, for example.

Comment: Also, a duplicate: [when to use _lessen_, when _decrease_, and when _reduce_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522266/when-to-use-lessen-when-decrease-and-when-reduce).

Comment: No word can be used interchangeably for any other word; there are always differences of syntax and collocation, not to speak of idioms and metaphors, that keep one word from substituting for another in **all** environments.

Comment: We cannot say 'Something is lessened to zero", but 'Reduced to zero' makes sense.

Comment: It should be "to [verb] **the** unemployment rate" or "to [verb] unemployment" (without the word "rate").

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use "lessen", when "decrease", and when "reduce"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522266/when-to-use-lessen-when-decrease-and-when-reduce)

Answer (score 1):

**Very short answer**: No.

**Short answer**: For many purposes — those where they mean decrease — Yes.

**Pedantic Answer**:

As @JohnLawler wisely wrote, “No word can be used interchangeably for any other word”. He may not have meant this more generally or subtly, but here are three specific examples where *reduce* cannot be replaced by *lessen* because it has a special usage:

> The officer was *reduced* to the ranks.

i.e. He was demoted. ([Definition 7 of *reduce* in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reduce))

> Pyruvic acid is *reduced* to ethanol during fermentation.

i.e. It undergoes the chemical change of addition of hydrogen or removal of oxygen. ([Definition 11 of *reduce* in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reduce))

> [She was *reduced* to tears.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reduce%20to%20tears)

She was affected to the extent that she started weeping.

**Footnote on the poster’s example**

This should be:

> The government is implementing its new policy to reduce unemployment.

The word *rate* is superfluous and meaningless here and in many similar circumstances. Whether to use reduce, lessen or decrease is a matter of taste here. In my experience *lessen* is least common.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer:

According to the dictionary, the definitions for both are the following:

> Reduce - make smaller or less in amount, degree, or size.
>
> Lessen - make or become less, diminish.

You may notice that the word lessen is in fact a synonym of reduce and vice versa. It would be appropriate to say:

*We must reduce the transmission rate of the virus.*

or

*We must lessen the transmission rate of the virus.*

Here both work interchangeably. However, depending on the context, it may be more expressive to use one or the other. For example, when strictly referring to size, one might say "I would like to reduce the size of my garden," rather than saying "I would like to lessen the size of my garden" although technically correct.

Another example of interchangeability:

*In order to make a more egalitarian society, we must reduce the wage gap.*

Is the same as saying

*In order to make a more egalitarian society, we must lessen the wage gap.*

Lessen may also be more commonly used referring to qualitative (effects) rather than explicit quantifiable measures, although again they can essentially be used interchangeably.

Comment: This answer would be much more convincing if it cited sources for the definitions and examples from respected sources for the use of the words in question.